# Big Blue Button HTML5Client not showing all features

Tags: bigbluebutton

I have a brand new BBB server and doing some tests right now.

My call for a user to join a meeting is like this:

https://bbb1.gingerbread.io/bigbluebutton/api/join?fullName=Jamie&meetingID=abc129&password=111222&joinViaHtml5=true&checksum=254c275d98ab84c8ee81fbe6fe53a90c4c7d8713

When I do this,  the user can join the conference and everything looks good. Except, there are GUI elements missing:

- No button to share screen
- No button to add people to the meeting
- No panel to collaborate in the presentation

Interestingly, when I launch the HTML client via the demo application, I can see all these elements in the UI. I could not identify which parameters I should pass to have the full list of features appear in the player.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I was joining the conference as a normal user instead of joining as guest (with moderator password). Once I used the moderator password I was able to see all those UI elements and features.